# Angular Material - How To Pass CSS Style To New Window

Tags: html, css, angular, printing, angular-material

I'm wanting to create my own simple print where I pass the `id` of a div to a function and print that div.  So far I've been able to accomplish that with bootstrap.

```
print(): void{
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById("table");

        let printWindow = window.open("");
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"></head><body>');

        printWindow.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        setTimeout(function(){printWindow.print();printWindow.close();},100);
 }
```

I load the boostrap css from the CDN.

However, I want to accomplish the same with Angular Material.  So, in my assets folder I copied the theme I am using (pink-bluegrey.css) and updated the link to be

```
href="assets/pink-bluegrey.css"
```

My app is able to fetch the stylesheet, however something is still wrong.  Either the sheet is not applied correctly or I am still missing other scripts / sheets.

[image: From the app]
From the app

[image: From the new print window] From the new print window

Comment: Unlike Bootstrap, Angular needs to run (JS) in order to display properly. Without JS, it's a simple `<div ng-app></div>`. That's all you get. The `ng-app` directive triggers the instantiation which effectively builds the elements of your app inside the browser.

Comment: I'm using Angular 5 not AngularJS, so I'm not using the `ng-app`, but I assume the same principle applies?

Comment: `ng-app` is a mere trigger and is irrelevant. The point is that Angular, in all past and future versions, uses JavaScript to build the app from scratch, based on that (or a different) trigger. Therefore, applying CSS without running the JavaScript will not produce a printable result. You might have to transform the existing elements into a string and try to recreate them as markup in the new doc, but it's still not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Even right clicking on the main page and printing doesn't render some of the Material styling.  Any idea on how to fix that.  For example, [https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)  try printing that page, the chips are unstyled.  Or will I have to rebuild what I'm trying to print so i can style it with bootstrap or something similar.

Comment: You might have better success at finding a working solution if you post what your real problem is - printing Angular Material screens. Passing CSS style to a new window is not your problem, it is an attempt at solving the printing problem. That might not be the correct or best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided if I need to print anything that is currently displayed in Angular Material, I'll just convert it to bootstrap and print it how I explained in my original question.

I looked at `jspdf` and `html2canvas` but they were both unreliable and didn't work as per the documentation.

I also added Material Design Lite (`css` and `js`) so I can combine both material and bootstrap.